# CDatabase thread safety

Tags: c++, database, mfc

I am using `CDatabase` to establish connection with a ODBC database. My concerns are

Are operations on `CDatabase` and related classes thread safe?

one of threads will open a connection (using `OpenEx`) on program stratup and then other threads will perform CRUD database operations. Will thiswork fine without any threading issues

Where could I get more information on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operations on `CDatabase` are not fully thread safe, and `CRecordset` even less. Each thread should use it's own instance of a `CRecordset` object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx6t3y0x.aspx